# Route to custom non-REST action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, action

I have "Articles" controller with REST routing.

I need one more action for it:

```
/articles/demo
```

It does't belongs to REST.

It just renders separate page, without consuming any models, etc.

Current routes.rb is following:

```
map.resources :articles
map.connect "articles/demo", :controller => "articles", :action => "demo"
```

Unfortunately, it does't works.

I get:

> Couldn't find Article with ID=demo

What's wrong here ?

Comment: By the way, your new `demo` action is not necessarily non-RESTful just because it's not one of GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE. REST is an architectural style that can be implemented by the HTTP methods, but not only by them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because it's after your map.resources put it before. First in First choose

```
map.connect "articles/demo", :controller => "articles", :action => "demo"
map.resources :articles
```